# Horizontal grid not matching y axis ticks

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
x=c(2.880262,3.405859,3.613575,3.744480,3.682059,3.694075,3.758320,4.034290,4.202741,4.309383,4.996279,5.981309,5.103148,4.926363,4.696024,5.522913,5.330382,4.434304,5.154567,6.247156,8.612752,9.996526,9.606994,10.303496,5.954970,5.688171,6.340349,6.252854,6.355642,5.988570,7.317148,11.664384,14.231579,16.489029,23.100640,20.280043,21.562793,24.311327,23.735198,23.796386,23.118181,23.269722,19.886981,20.000975,19.967642,24.278910,17.447721,14.536114,20.646378,19.096832,20.258060,19.803196)
y=1:52
w=c(-2784,-2897,-2897,-2066,-2466,-2466,-2466,-2466,-2102,-2102,-2102,-2202,-2094,-2094,-2094,-2094,-1691,-1691,-1691,-1691,-1691,-1674,-1774,-1774,-2019,-2019,-2019,-2019,-2019,-1988,-1988,-1988,-1988,-1988,-1888,-1888,-1888,-1888,-1888,-1888,-1888,-1488,-2051,-2051,-2051,-2051,-2315,-2315,-2315)
v=1:49
```

When I try to plot these, my grid does not match the tick marks.  Is there a way to fix this in base?

```
plot(y,x,type='l',col='blue',log='y')
grid(NA,NULL)
```

Resulting plot:

[image: Image of plot with grid issue]

And the other plot:

```
plot(v,w,type='l',yaxt='n')
grid(NA,NULL)
axis(2,pretty(w),format(pretty(w)/1000,big.mark=','))
```

Result:

[image: Image of plot with grid issue]

I put both up because I am using different techniques to label the y axis, and one is a log chart while the other is not.  By the way, I have hundreds of other data sets that are placing the grid lines by the tick marks.  It is just these two that are not matching grids to ticks.

Comment: From the help page: "If more fine tuning is required, use abline(h = ., v = .) directly."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first plot, just use `equilogs=F`.

For the second plot, since you are using non-default axis ticks, I think you'll have to resort to `abline` like it says in `?grid`. Good luck!

Comment: This worked.  Also, `abline(h=pretty(w),lty=3,col='gray')` worked for the second example.